# Nuxt JS dynamic param on nested page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create a dynamic param for one of my nuxt JS pages and am struggling to figure out the correct folder structure, the URL I need will be something like:

- https://example.com/landing/123

Where 123 is my dynamic param that I need to grab using `this.$route`.

I've tried the following folder markups:

- pages/_landing/index.vue
- pages/landing/_index.vue

How can I achieve this?

I still need the page to load even if my param isn't supplied

Answer (score -1):

use the [ ] syntax

```
pages/landing/[paramName].vue
```

further read
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes

Comment: There is no indication that OP is using Nuxt3.

Comment: I'm using Nuxt JS 2. Nuxt JS 3 hasn't been made stable yet.

Answer (score -1):

If 123 is the id, you need to save the file as `_id.vue` then you can get the value of id using `this.$route.params.id`

Edit: You directory structure will be `pages/landing/_id.vue`